# how can I register app id into ejabberd server's database?

Tags: xmpp, registration, ejabberd

We are using a mobile `xmpp` client to chat with `ejabberd` server. During the registration, we want the following fields: **`JID, Password, appID`** to be sent to the `xmpp` server.

Which module should I look into to incorporate this change? I also want to store the `appID` in ejaberd's users table in the database. Further in our current installation we can see the password.  Which module of `ejabberd` should I invoke to encrypt store the passwords. Also can we verify the user using the encrypted password? Any suggestion and pointers to the right direction will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are using a mobile xmpp client to chat with ejabberd server. During
>   the registration, we want the following fields: JID, Password and the
>   appID to be sent to the xmpp server ( ejabberd here). Which module
>   should I look into to incorporate this change?  I also want to store
>   the appID in ejaberd's users table in the database.

mod_register only takes username and password during registration. If you want to store other details during registration, you would have to modify the source code of that module. Or you can store the appid and any other information in the account vcard, once the account is created and the client logins to it.

> Further in our current installation we can see the password . which
>   module of ejabberd should I invoke to encrypt the password and store
>   the encrypted passwords. Also can we verify the user using the
>   encrypted password? Any suggestion and pointers to the right direction
>   will be of great help.

If you enable SCRAM in ejabberd configuration file, the passwords will be stored scrammed (that is, encrypted).

Comment: Since I already have some users, what I am doing is first running the code ejabberd_auth_odbc:convert_to_scram(<<"example.org">>) to update the database. Then I will add the SCRAM option and restart ejabberd. The tables are already update with the extra fields. I hope I am doing this correct, based on the documentation here: https://www.ejabberd.im/node/24818/. Kindly let me know if I am doing it right or not.

Comment: Hi Badlop, It gave me a few errors, but at last I think the problem is solved. New users are getting registered using SCRAM. Thanks.

Comment: I need a clarification. When we want to store email address, name, surname, telephone number, mobile number, is there a a specific XML format I must follow to add the vcard details or do I create my own XML tags?

Comment: I created a VCard for an user using gajim client and checked the database. For the telephone number it uses the following XML '<TEL><HOME/><NUMBER>9674426420</NUMBER></TEL>'. Do we have to maintain this protocol while adding vcard or do different applications create their own XML formatting? For  the appID is there any specific tag that should be used in the vcard? Further is there any documentation in regards to this?

Comment: See http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html for vCard fields. For appID, you could use an existing one that you consider nobody else will care to use.